# Angular 2 can't use custom directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angular2-modules

This is the `shared` module which I share across my app:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ModalModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    ModalModule
  ]
})

export class SharedModule {}
```

This `shared` module imports `ModalModule`:

```
import {ModalCloseDirective, ModalOpenDirective, ModalApiService, ModalCloseComponent} from './shared';
import {ModalComponent} from './modal.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ModalCloseDirective,
    ModalOpenDirective,
    ModalComponent,
    ModalCloseComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ModalCloseDirective,
    ModalOpenDirective,
    ModalComponent,
    ModalCloseComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    ModalApiService
  ]
})

export class ModalModule {}
```

Then I have a third module, which imports `SharedModule` (which exports the `ModalModule`):

```
import {SharedModule} from '../../shared';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: 'documentation',
        component: DocumentationComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: DocumentationListComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]),
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    DocumentationListComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class documentationModule {}
```

And then I have this directive `modalOpen`:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[modalOpen]'
})

export class ModalOpenDirective {

  modalOpen: string;

  constructor(private modalApi: ModalApiService) {}

  @HostListener('click')
  open(): void {
    this.modalApi.open(this.modalOpen);
  }
}
```

But when I use it inside of `DocumentationListComponent`'s template:

```
<span [(modalOpen)]="new-item">Add item</span>
```

I get this:

```
Can't bind to 'modalOpen' since it isn't a known property of 'span'
```

Why can't it find the directive in my template?

**EDIT:** What I want is basically a feature module from this guide: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Comment: I believe you want to use ModalOpenDirective throughout your application. right?

Comment: @micronyks Yes, I've got a whole lot of directives that needs to be shared like this.

Comment: Then why are you declaring it within ModalModule ? declare it within sharedmodule only.

Comment: @micronyks Because I want to group functionality and then export only `ModalModule` to the `SharedModule`. Declaring it right inside `SharedModule` doesn't work either because that's the way I had it at first, something is wrong somewhere but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: @micronyks I believe it's called a **feature** module: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Comment: Do you have your `@Input` and `@Output` in the directive?

Comment: @peeskillet Nope, but that comment/answer just made me realise what's happening. Every time I used `[]` or `[()]` it treated it as a native attribute of the span instead of the directive. I can't use it like that so I just added an extra input of the directive and it works the way it should. Sometimes you shouldn't try to take shortcuts like this hehe.

Answer (score 0):

I just realised why it isn't working, so I'll leave an explanation here in case other people get stuck on this as well. Basically when you use `[modalOpen]` or `[(modalOpen)]` it throws an error, because if you use those it will think that the `span` element has `modalOpen` as an attribute, which it doesn't.

So instead I added an `@Input() modalId` to the `modalOpen` directive and pass the id like this instead:

```
<span modalOpen modalId="new-item">Add item</span>
```

and it works.

Kudos to @peeskillet for making me realise this.

Comment: You could also add a input like this in the modal open directive, @Input() modalOpen; @Output('modalOpen') onModalOpen: EventEmitter<any>. And then you can pass the data with [(modalOpen)]="data"

Comment: @Nicu Thanks, I'll try that.